# Restrict access to my external own websites for the paid users in main website

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a membership website in my subdomain built in wordpress.

Iam actually installing saas php scripts for various uses for my paid users.

My issue is my membership website is built with wordpress and my other sub directory websites are in PHP scripts.

Now the problem is i want to provide the access to all those PHP script tools exclusive for my paid members in my website.

I for now creating individual access to them for all 7 tools and mailing them the details. Which is taking me 20 min for each user.

I need to know any code or technique to make my work very easy.

My actual idea was to merge all the databases in main database so people can use same login for every tool. But, all the other variables are so different.

Iam unable to figure out. Please help.

My actual idea was to merge all the databases in main database so people can use same login for every tool. But, all the other variables are so different.

Iam unable to figure out. Please help.

Comment: You might do well to ask this on [wordpress.se]

Comment: My suggestion would be to merge the two sites and try to convert your "PHP scripts" to either a plugin or a theme template, depending on what they actually do. It might sound like a lot of work, but it also might not really be that much. There's lots of parts of WordPress that just _happen_ to have a WordPress header and footer, but the inner parts don't need to invoke anything WordPress-related if they don't want to.